# Memory address of an integer in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the memory address for a low-memory trick from an int pointer in C#. However, when I check the output, it seems to be printing the int's value, not its memory address. Below is my code:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(newBuilder))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("Data");

                GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(Nodes, GCHandleType.Normal); 
                //fixed(int * p = &Nodes[0].value) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Nodes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("Node");
                        writer.WriteStartElement("Value");
                        writer.WriteValue(this.Nodes[i].Value);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                        fixed (int* name = &Nodes[i].value)
                        {

                            writer.WriteStartElement("Name");
                            writer.WriteValue(name->ToString());
                            writer.WriteEndElement();

                        }

                        if (Nodes[i].Parent1 != null)
                        {
                            fixed (int* parent1 = &Nodes[i].Parent1.value)
                            {

                                writer.WriteStartElement("Parent1");
                                writer.WriteValue(parent1->ToString());
                                writer.WriteEndElement();
                            }
                        }
                        if (Nodes[i].Parent2 != null) {

                        fixed (int* parent2 = &Nodes[i].Parent2.value)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Parent2");
                            writer.WriteValue(parent2->ToString());
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }
                    }
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                //}
                handle.Free();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
                //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Node>));
                //serializer.Serialize(writer, this.Nodes);

            }
```

Any idea why it's doing that?

Thanks

Comment: The reason you get the value instead of the adress is that the -> operator doesn't just do member access but also implicitly dereferences. So, name->ToString() is the same as (*name).ToString().

Comment: The a->b operator works like (*a).b so you're dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: Why would anyone ever want to write the address of a temporarily fixed value to an XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `((IntPtr)name).ToString()`. `name->ToString()` calls the `ToString` method on the `int` pointed to by `name`.

Comment: Hmm. That does appear to be giving me the memory locations. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Your code writes the value of the integer, because you [dereference the pointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h.aspx) and invoke the [ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx) on the integer value.